# How do you show that $n = 3$ is the only positive solution to $2^{n-1} = n+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know, if there as a quick way to do this.

Comment: When $n$ increases, the left-hand side doubles, and the right-hand side only increases by $1$.

Comment: If $n$ grows by $1$, the left hand side grows by at least $4$ (if $n\ge3$), the right hand side only by $1$.

Comment: Well, one thing to note is that powers of $2$ get big fast so $2^{n-1} > n+1$ for nearly all $n$.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer or a real number?

Comment: The question is far more interesting if we treat it as $n$ being real.  For that, when considering the region $(0,3)$ some more care needs to be taken, especially since there does exist another real solution but it happens to be negative, but we'd need to know what tools the OP has available to use.  Derivatives hopefully?  Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: I only need $n$ as an integer

Comment: Then "calculus" is not the correct tag.

Comment: @JMoravitz I can use all these tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if $n$ increases by $1$ than $n+1$ increases from $n+1$ to $(n+1)+1$ and increases by $1$.

But as $n$ increases by $1$ then $2^{n-1}$ increases from $2^{n-1}$ to $2^n = 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1}$ and increasess be $2^{n-1}$.  ANd if $n > 1$ then $2^{n-1} > 1$ so $2^{n-1}$ is increasing by more than $n+1$ is increasing.

So $2^{n-1}$ outpaces $n+1$ and will they will never be equal again.

Alternatively

with calculus:

Let $f(n) = 2^{n-1} - n-1$ then $f'(n)=\ln n * 2^{n-1} -1$ and if $n>1$ then $f'(n) > 0$ and $f(n)$ is increasing.  So $f(3) =0$ and $f(n)\ne 0$ for any $n \ge 1$ and $n \ne 3$.

Of course this raises the question is there any $n < 1$ where $f(n) = 0$ and the answer is, by mean value theorem and noting $f(-2) = \frac 18-1 < 0$, is "yes".

Answer (score 2):

Use induction to show that $2^{n-1} > n + 1$ for $n \ge 4$.
The base case of $n = 4$ is certainly true.
For $n \ge 5$ note that
$$2^n = 2\cdot2^{n-1} > 2(n + 1) = 2n + 2 > n + 2.$$

Comment: Thank you! My own idea was more complicated..